# Cannot find data type 'UserDefinedType' despite being declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, roundhouse

The following script creates a stored procedure (mysproc.sql):

```
/* A table type with 1 column (NVARCHAR(200)) of names */
CREATE TYPE [SchemaName].[NameList] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](200)
)
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [SchemaName].[AlterNameAccess] 
@pNames AS [SchemaName].[NameList] READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN

        -- Logic Here ...

    END
GO
```

When the script above is ran, another script is ran that calls the stored procedure is called like so (runsproc.sql):

```
DECLARE @Names AS [SchemaName].[NameList]

INSERT INTO @Names -- Logic ...

EXEC [SchemaName].[AlterNameAccess] 
@pNames = @Names
```

RoundhousE is used to run these scripts in order... locally RoundhousE will run these scripts correctly, however when running RoundhousE on Azure an error occurs when `DECLARE @Names AS [SchemaName].[NameList]` is declared... saying the user defined type is not being defined despite it actually being defined.

Here is the error message RoundHousE provides:

```
2019-09-17 18:52:04,358 [INFO ] -  Running runsproc.sql on (local)
2019-09-17 18:52:06,686 [ERROR] - 
*** Error executing file 'runsproc.sql'. ***

2019-09-17 18:52:06,701 [ERROR] - Database deployment encountered an error. You were running in a transaction though, so the database should be in the state it was in prior to this piece running. This does not include a drop/create or any creation of a database, as those items can not run in a transaction.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type SchemaName.NameList.
Must declare the table variable "@Names".
Must declare the table variable "@Names".
Parameter or variable '@Names' has an invalid data type.
```

Comment: Hi. According to my error message, you may not successfully create the stored procedure when you run the script  ```runsproc.sql```. Please try to run the script after the stored procedure is successfully created.

Comment: @JimXu according to RoundhousE logs, the sproc script runs successfully on deployment.

Comment: According to your error message, when you run the ```sproc ```, your sql database does not have data type SchemaName.NameList. So I think you need to run sproc script after you run the script mysproc successfully.